# R: How can I integrate these data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames I would like to integrate.

Data frame 1 (Terminals) consists of the following:

```
peertermid <- c(1,2,3,4)
peertermlatt <- c(23,34,56,44)
peertermlong <- c(23,34,56,44)
Terminals <- data.frame(peertermid, peertermlatt, peertermlong)
```

Data frame 2 (Lanes) consists of the following:

```
laneid <- c(1,2,3,4)
olatt <- c(23,34,56,44)
olong <- c(23,34,56,44)
dlatt <- c(23,34,56,44)
dlong <- c(23,34,56,44)
Lanes <- data.frame(laneid, olatt, olong, dlatt, dlong)
```

I would like to combine these two data frames to get the following Master data frame:

```
mlaneid <- c(1)
mpeertermid <- c(1)
mpeertermlatt <- c(22)
mpeertermlong <- c(22)
molatt <- c(22)
molong <- c(22)
mdlatt <- c(22)
mdlong <- c(22)
master <- data.frame(mlaneid, mpeertermid, mpeertermlatt, mpeertermlong, molatt, molong, mdlatt, mdlong)
```

Master data frame should be organized so that for each row in the Lanes data frame, I am adding all of the relevant rows from the Terminals data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```r
merge(x = Terminals, y = Lanes, by.y ="laneid", by.x = "peertermid", all = TRUE)

#Output
#   peertermid peertermlatt peertermlong olatt olong dlatt dlong
# 1          1           23           23    23    23    23    23
# 2          2           34           34    34    34    34    34
# 3          3           56           56    56    56    56    56
# 4          4           44           44    44    44    44    44
```

Comment: Not quite, for each laneID, I would like to loop through all of the terminal IDs.  So in my example, the resulting data frame should have 16 rows (i.e. 4 x 4 from the two input data frames).

Comment: In that case you can simply do `merge(x = Lanes, y = Terminals)`.